# Create macro that hides rows with specific word in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create a macro that hides rows when a cell contains the word "apple" or "orange". The problem that I can't seem to fix is that the cells in which "apple" and "orange" may appear have other words around them like "banana", "strawberry", "pineapple", etc. While my macro works when only "apple" or "orange" appears in a cell, it does not work when one of those words are combined with other words. Can someone help me please? I am currently using Office 365 for Mac/Excel version 16.16.2 See macro I'm using now below:

```
`BeginRow = 4
EndRow = 2844
ChkCol = 5

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "Apple" Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "Orange" 
     Then Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else 
     Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If 
Next RowCnt`
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of =, you should use Like:

```
BeginRow = 4 EndRow = 2844 ChkCol = 5

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow 
   If UCase(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value) Like "*APPLE*" Or UCase(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value) Like "*ORANGE*" Then  
      Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True 
   Else Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False 
   End If 
Next RowCnt
```

This will hide the rows that contain "apple" and/or "orange" (case insensitive).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this route, since it would allow for easily scaling the number of words to hide - by adding to the words array. Though I'd still use `LIKE` as @emma-clarke suggested.

```
Dim beginrow As Integer, endrow As Integer, chkcol As Integer, rowcnt As Integer, i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, r As Range
Dim words() As String

words = Split("Apple,Taco", ",")
beginrow = 1
endrow = 22
chkcol = 1
Set rng = Range(Cells(beginrow, chkcol), Cells(endrow, chkcol))
For Each r In rng
    For i = 0 To UBound(words)
        If UCase(r.Value) Like UCase("*" & words(i) & "*") Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden Then Exit For
    Next i
Next r
Set r = Nothing
Set rng = nothing
```

Comment: Thanks @emma-clarke and BamAlmighty. One question - do I have to use the * symbol when referring to Apple or Orange like Emma has in her example?  Like "*APPLE*"

Comment: Hi Laura - the * symbol is called a wildcard, and is what allows you to hide cells that have more than just "apple" in it. Like "APPLE" will only hide a cell with value "apple". Like "\*APPLE\*" will hide a cell that has apple anywhere in it - "123applewatermelon", for example.